# Is ”what there is a reason to do” a valid construct?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, legalese, relative-clauses

From page 76 of Frederick Schauer’s *Thinking Like a Lawyer*:

> **What there is a reason to do** is different
>   from what should be done, all things considered, just as **what there is a
>   right to do** is different from what the right-holder actually gets to do, all
>   things considered.

Is this subject correct? If so, would someone please explain and gloss it?

I can’t pinpoint why, but it sounds wrong. I guess its meaning is “What should be done due to a reason. . . .”

**Supplementary**: Thanks to the answer below, I now apprehend the meaning of my sentence, but I still find the construction confusing.  Would you please explain, in more detail, why this is 'essentially not (very) different from these examples'?

Comment: Both of those constructions using *what there is a* sound odd to me (AmE).

Answer (score 3):

> What there is a reason to do...
>   What there is a right to do...

Can be parsed as

> The things [for which there exists a reason to do them]...
>   The things [for which there exists a right to do them...

What the author says is that what *should be done* is not the same collection of things for which there is a reason for them to be done.

Let's say there is a good reason why I would quit my job (I find it boring). What the author says is that the simple fact that a reason *exists* for quitting my job does *not* mean that I *should* quit my job, *all things considered*. After all, there may be many reasons for *not* quitting.

The construction of the sentence may look a bit confusing but it is essentially not (very) different from these examples:

> (A man's gotta do) *what a man's gotta do*.
>   *What needs to be said* is that not everyone agreed on this.
>   *What vegetables were left* had started rotting already.
>   *What there is evidence to believe* should be further investigated.

In all cases, *what* refers to a concept that is described by what follows:

> [a man's gotta do (*something*)) -> What [a man's gotta do]
>   [(*something*) needs to be said] -> What [needs to be said]
>  
>   [(*some*) vegetables were left] -> What [vegetables were left]
>   [there is evidence to believe (*something*)] -> What [there is evidence to believe]
>   [there is a reason to do (*something*)] -> What [there is a reason to do]

Comment: ... 'What there is a reason to do is different from what should be done, all things considered' would more normally be phrased along these lines: 'The fact that reasons can be found for doing something doesn't guarantee that it's the wisest course of action'.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please explain in more on detail why this is 'essentially not (very) different from these examples'? I now apprehend the meaning of my sentence, but I still find the construction confusing. 
Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?

Comment: @LePressentiment I added a bit, including an extra example. Hope it clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thank you again. Would you please check `by the what follows`? What does this refer to?

Comment: I also enlarged on this at http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37779/8712